# escaping closure in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I have read a lot of material on stack overflow and I just cannot figure this one out:

I have been this line of code from an online source for hours and I just don't know why the closure that is being passed into a function is escaping, here is the code:

```
func composeFunction(functionA: @escaping (Int) -> String, functionB:  @escaping (String) -> String) -> ((Int) -> String) { 

    return {

        number in 

        functionB(functionA(number))
    }
}
```

From apple's documentation, closures are escaping when:
1) Asynchronous operation that runs on a background thread
2) The closure is interactive with properties outside of it's scope (using `self`)

But I don't see those are happening, many help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    number in 
    functionB(functionA(number))
}
```

is a closure. Returning it causes both `functionB` and `functionA` to escape, because it becomes unknown at what point this closure will be called or deallocated.

This is different from just `return functionB(functionA(number))`, which causes the immediate invocation of both of those functions, and causes them to never escape the `composeFunction` context.

Comment: Thanks, so correct me if I'm wrong, the reason why `functionA` and `functionB` is escaping is because the `composeFunction` doesn't know when the return closure is called?

Comment: @BrendonCheung Not so much that it doesn't know when it's called, but that it doesn't know when it's deallocated. For all it knows, the result of the `composeFunction` call could be stored indefinitely, thus keeping escaping references to functionA/B alive, indefinitely

Comment: Well wouldn't the return closure be called as soon as I call `composeFunction(functionA: randomFuncA, functionB: randonFuncB)`?

Comment: @BrendonCheung no it would not, it would be called when you invoke what compose function returned since it's returning a closure

Comment: @Alexander Okay so because the returned function from `composeFunction` call doesn't know when it needs to be deallocated, hence it needs to reference `functionA` and `functionB` to keep the returned function alive? (wow this is crazy!)

Comment: @TPN1994 why wouldn't this function work if `functionA` and `functionB` are non-escaping?

Comment: @BrendonCheung I don't think the compiler would let you have it nonescaping afaik. But, let's say it was possible, the references inside `functionA` and `functionB` would most likely be deallocated right away (depends on how things are deallocated in swift) and it would crash at the return line

Comment: @BrendonCheung Say I did `let foo = composeFunctions(bar, baz)`. `foo` could be a short-lived local variable, or I could assign it to a global variable and have it retained for the life of the program. There's no way for it to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

your func `composeFunction` returns a `((Int) -> (String))` and that is exactly a closure. Of course now this means functionA and functionB are going to be escaping because we don't know when and where this closure will be called. Moreover, this is because it needs to know if it should keep the reference to the objects passed in / being manipulated. For example, if all your closure parameters had `(() -> Void)` instead and you also returned `(() -> Void)` then it would not need to be escaping.